# Mi aplicación de React Redux no obtiene datos de la API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Estoy realizando una aplicación de React integrando Redux, pero no se guardan los items en el estado. Me gustaría saber cuál puede ser el problema. Gracias

```js
//Componente Artículos

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Page from './page'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

//Action Redux
import {fetchArticulos} from "../redux/actions/articulos";

//Stylesheet
import './styles.css'

class Articulos extends Component{

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(fetchArticulos())
        console.log(this.props.articulos, 'items')
    }

    sayHello = ()=>{
        console.log("HELLO")
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <Page sayHello={this.sayHello}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    articulos: state.articulos.items,
    loading: state.articulos.loading,
    error: state.articulos.error
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Articulos)
```

```js
//Redux Action

function getArticulos() {
    return fetch('https://api123.com/api/articulos/all')
        .then(handleErrors)
        .then(res => res.json())
}

export function fetchArticulos() {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(fetchArticulosBegin());
        return getArticulos()
            .then(json => {
                dispatch(fetchArticulosSuccess(json.articulos));
                return json.articulos;
            })
            .catch(error =>
                dispatch(fetchArticulosFailure(error))
            );
    };
}

// Handle HTTP errors since fetch won't.
function handleErrors(response) {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw Error(response.statusText);
    }
    return response;
}

export const FETCH_ARTICULOS_BEGIN = "FETCH_ARTICULOS_BEGIN";
export const FETCH_ARTICULOS_SUCCESS = "FETCH_ARTICULOS_SUCCESS";
export const FETCH_ARTICULOS_FAILURE = "FETCH_ARTICULOS_FAILURE";

export const fetchArticulosBegin = () => ({
    type: FETCH_ARTICULOS_BEGIN
});

export const fetchArticulosSuccess = articulos => ({
    type: FETCH_ARTICULOS_SUCCESS,
    payload: { articulos }
});

export const fetchArticulosFailure = error => ({
    type: FETCH_ARTICULOS_FAILURE,
    payload: { error }
});
```

```js
//Redux Reducer

import {
    FETCH_ARTICULOS_BEGIN,
    FETCH_ARTICULOS_SUCCESS,
    FETCH_ARTICULOS_FAILURE
} from "../actions/articulos";

const initialState = {
    items: [],
    loading: false,
    error: null
};

export default function productReducer(
    state = initialState,
    action
) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_ARTICULOS_BEGIN:
            // Mark the state as "loading" so we can show a spinner or something
            // Also, reset any errors. We're starting fresh.
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true,
                error: null
            };

        case FETCH_ARTICULOS_SUCCESS:
            console.log('SUCCESS')
            // All done: set loading "false".
            // Also, replace the items with the ones from the server
            console.log(action.payload.articulos)
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                items: action.payload.articulos
            };

        case FETCH_ARTICULOS_FAILURE:
            console.log('FAILURE')
            // The request failed, but it did stop, so set loading to "false".
            // Save the error, and we can display it somewhere
            // Since it failed, we don't have items to display anymore, so set it empty.
            // This is up to you and your app though: maybe you want to keep the items
            // around! Do whatever seems right.
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                error: action.payload.error,
                items: []
            };

        default:
            // ALWAYS have a default case in a reducer
            return state;
    }
}
```

```js
//Combine reducer

import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import articulos from "./articulos";

export default combineReducers({
    articulos
});
```

```js
//Index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

//ReactRouter
import {BrowserRouter, Redirect, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";

//Bootstrap
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'

//Components
import Articulos from './articulos'
import Header from './header'
import {Container} from "reactstrap";

//Redux
import { createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import root from './redux/reducers/root'
import {Provider} from "react-redux";

const store = createStore(root, applyMiddleware(thunk))

const Root = () =>(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
                <Header/>
                <Container>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path='/articulos' component={Articulos}/>
                        <Redirect from='/' to='/articulos'/>
                    </Switch>
                </Container>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
)

ReactDOM.render(<Root />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: Se muestra algún error en la consola, creaste tu store? Creo sería máas fácil saber cuál es el problema.

Comment: Hola, creé el Store con esta línea de código en mi index.js del proyecto: "const store = createStore(root, applyMiddleware(thunk))" En la consola no se muestra ningún error. Agregué el index.js, quizá ahí pueda estar el error.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar esto en tu componente de Articulos:

```
+ import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
+ const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  getAarticulos: bindActionCreators(fetchArticulos, bind)
});

+ export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Articulos)
```

De esa manera en tu componentDidMount lo llamarías como `this.props.getArticulos()`